# Very often PyQt5 QMediaPlayer displays an error message when opening a media file

Tags: pyqt5, directshow, qmediaplayer, lavfilters

When I open the file, the console displays the error message

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040218 (IDispatch error #24)
```

and the media file itself does not play. But if I try to open the media file again, it will most likely open and play without error. And this problem happens very often when opening media files (mp4, mp3, etc.).
I am using:
Windows 10 x64 1809
PyQt5 5.15.10
LAV Filters latest version from K-Lite Codec Pack.

After I noticed that the file was opening without error after reopening it after an error, I thought that the reason was that I had not terminated the previous media before opening the new one and the codecs simply did not have time to close from the previous file. I implemented a function that stops the playing media file and setVideoOutput to None. This function was run before opening the new file, but it did not produce any results.
I also tried downloading an older version of LAV Filters, but without success.
The function itself stops:

```
self.player.stop()
self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent())
self.player.setVideoOutput(None)
```

A minimal example of the complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

class Player(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Player, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget(self)

        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

        self.open_button = QPushButton("Open Media File")
        self.open_button.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.open_button)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def open_file(self):
        file_dialog = QFileDialog()
        file_dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)
        if file_dialog.exec_() == QFileDialog.Accepted:
            selected_file = file_dialog.selectedUrls()[0].toString()
            self.stop_and_clear(selected_file)

    def stop_and_clear(self, selected_file):
        self.media_player.stop()
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent())
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(None)

        self.set_and_play_file(selected_file)

    def set_and_play_file(self, selected_file):
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(selected_file)))
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)
        self.media_player.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = Player()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This error code is `VFW_E_CANNOT_RENDER` and is a pretty high level faliure indicating that this specific media file is not supported, for whatever reason.

Comment: @RomanR. What do you mean, unsupported? I wrote that when I try to open the same file again, it opens without this error and plays without problems.

Comment: Unsupported means that there was a problem when playback was set up and this failure was forwarded to your application as an indication that this file can't be played. If it opens from time to time, it means that one of the internal components, "codecs", might be not that stable. The fact that you are using K-Lite makes it even more convoluted, in the way that one of these components you brought into your system might be letting it down and fail the entire playback attempt.

Comment: DirectShow itself is very fliexble an "open" in terms of letting you extend the framework by external software items. The other side of this is that you are expected to be able to troubleshoot the problems like the reported one: be able to identify those faulty pieces of software that affect the entire framework. And then codec pack is just a collection of software pieces not necessarily of good quality (even though we believe those to be okay).

Comment: @RomanR. Both with codec pack and without, still in my case there is no difference in the error. Well, so far I have implemented such logic that at this error, the opened media file tries to open 10 more times, and for these 10 times in most cases this error bypasses me, although tormenting me with its messages in the console. Well, I can't even imagine why I have this problem to fully solve it, because I haven't seen this in other media players that use LAV Filters.

Comment: @ツDeeffest笑 When dealing with such "random" issues, you have to be patient and try to exclude options. 1. Ensure that the file is *valid* and not corrupted: as said above, when using unofficial or unreliable codec packs, more elements come in play, and an unstable codec may give different results even with the same file; 2. try to recreate the media file through ffmpeg using the `-codec copy` flag, and check the output for errors; 3. test the code on other machines with the above files. Finally, if your Qt was built with the ffmpeg backend, try it, or eventually consider switching to Qt6.